# display Image with options in react-select 2

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to add image with each option in react-select v2 using react-avatar.

Here is what i tried so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import createClass from 'create-react-class';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Select from 'react-select';
import Avatar from 'react-avatar';

const USERS = [
  {
    value: 'John Smith', label: 'John Smith', email: 'john@smith.com', avatar: '',
  },
  {
    value: 'Merry Jane', label: 'Merry Jane', email: 'merry@jane.com', avatar: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Hrithik_at_Rado_launch.jpg/220px-Hrithik_at_Rado_launch.jpg',
  },
  {
    value: 'Stan Hoper', label: 'Stan Hoper', email: 'stan@hoper.com', avatar: 'https://adminui.liscio.me/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/james_wurbs.png',
  },
];
const GRAVATAR_SIZE = 30;

const stringOrNode = PropTypes.oneOfType([
  PropTypes.string,
  PropTypes.node,
]);

const GravatarOption = createClass({
  propTypes: {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    className: PropTypes.string,
    isDisabled: PropTypes.bool,
    isFocused: PropTypes.bool,
    isSelected: PropTypes.bool,
    onFocus: PropTypes.func,
    onSelect: PropTypes.func,
    option: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  },
  handleMouseDown(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.props.onSelect(this.props.option, event);
  },
  handleMouseEnter(event) {
    this.props.onFocus(this.props.option, event);
  },
  handleMouseMove(event) {
    if (this.props.isFocused) return;
    this.props.onFocus(this.props.option, event);
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={this.props.className}
        onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
        onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
        onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}>
        <Avatar round size={GRAVATAR_SIZE} className="avatar" color="#0366d6" name={this.props.option.label} src={this.props.option.avatar} />
        {this.props.option.label}
      </div>
    );
  },
});

const GravatarValue = createClass({
  propTypes: {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    placeholder: stringOrNode,
    value: PropTypes.object,
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Select-value">
        <span className="Select-value-label">
          <Avatar round size={GRAVATAR_SIZE} className="avatar" color="#0366d6" name={this.props.value.label} src={this.props.value.avatar} />
          {this.props.value.label}
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  },
});

const UsersField = createClass({
  propTypes: {
    hint: PropTypes.string,
    label: PropTypes.string,
  },
  getInitialState() {
    return {};
  },
  setValue(value) {
    this.setState({ value });
  },
  render() {
    const placeholder = <span>&#9786; Select User</span>;

    return (
      <div className="section text-left">
        <Select
          onChange={this.setValue}
          components={{ Option: GravatarOption, Value: GravatarValue }}
          options={USERS}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          value={this.state.value}
          />
      </div>
    );
  },
});

export default UsersField;
```

This example is not working as the prop option is not defined. However in the example it works fine with react-select v1 but it's not working with react-select v2.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please, try to set up a codesandbox or similar example

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: @stack26 It says the prop 'option' is not defined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you'll want to make sure to pass on the innerRef and innerProps to your Option or it won't fire the mouseover and click events (this is in the documentation, but not noted well). Here's an example:

```
const Option = props => {
  const { innerProps, innerRef } = props;
  return (
    <article ref={innerRef} {...innerProps} className={'custom-option'}>
      <h4>{props.data.artist}</h4>
      <div className={'sub'}>{props.data.title} </div>
    </article>
  );
};

<Select {...selectProps} components={{Option}}/>
```

Next, the 'value' displayed in the Control is either a SingleValue or a MultiValue, depending on isMulti. To control the display of SingleValue's label you override SingleValue. To override the display of a MultiValue you're probably overriding MultiValueLabel. All of this is laid out in the [Components documentation](https://react-select.com/components), with examples.

Last, you can see from my Option example above that the option `data` is where your object is stored. Your Option should probably only require something like this:

```
import { components } from 'react-select';

const Option = props => {
  const {data} = props;
  return (
    <components.Option {...props}>
      <Avatar round size={GRAVATAR_SIZE} className="avatar" color="#0366d6" name={data.label} src={data.avatar} />
      {data.label}
    </components.Option>
  );
};
```

Comment: @t1gor glad I could help